# Besided speed skating, were there more world championships that did not gave a world champion?

Tags: history, speed-skating

The World Allround Speed Skating Championships have been held since 1893. In the tournament, four distances are skated. Up to 1907, the World Champion was the skater who won at least three distances. If no participant won more than two distances, there was no world champion.

In those 15 years, it happened five times that the tournament had no winner, thus there was no world champion.

Are there more examples of major sports (let's say sports that have been Olympic) that had world championships that did not have winners? My personal focus is on the years 1893 to 1907, to provide context to the speed skating tournament, but examples from every time period are welcome.

(I don't mean championships were something unexpected happened, such as disqualifications or withdrawals, or outcomes that the organizers forgot to make rules for, such as participants being tied on points without tie-breakers. I mean championships where the rules were such that a not-so-extreme outcome could lead to having no world champion.)

Comment: I don't know where to put this, but the 'tag' for 'speed-skating' says: "For questions about the sport of speed skating. Avoid use of the tag for ice-skating unless the question also directly applies to it." I have no idea what the second sentence tries to tell me. Speed skating is on ice, so wouldn't the tag always apply? Not trying to be pedantic, I am confused when I should use 'ice-skating' and when I should use 'speed-skating', and the text does not help at all.

Comment: I'm confused as well. Rather than discuss it here, [I've started a discussion in The Clubhouse](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49290478#49290478). Please contribute :-)

Comment: I think ‘ice skating’ is more generic than ‘speed skating’, so might apply to questions such as how to skate faster playing hockey, or such.